# foreach using split in C# and return Json result

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc

IN MY CONTROLLER

```
var data1 = data.Split(','); 
List opsi = new List(); 
foreach (string da1 in data1) 
{ 
    string[] data2 = da1.Split(':'); 
    opsi.Add(data2[0]); 
} 

return Json(new 
{ 
    info = form["jml_soal"].ToString(), 
    data = opsi 
});
```

**Actual result** :  `1,2,3,4,5`
**Expected Result** : `B,C,D,A,D`

Please Help!

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible example please, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: yes, this looks working so far, if `data` is for example "[1:B,2:C,3:D,4:A,5:D]", you might wanna change `data2[0]` to `data2[1]`, if not please at least tell us what your input `data` actually is

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the opsi.Add(data2[0]) to opsi.Add(data2[1])

Attention to first and last character

```
string data = "[1:B,2:C,3:D,4:A,5:D]";

List<string> opsi = new List<string>();

//adding a substring to remove the first and last character [ and ]
var data1 = data.Substring(1, data.Length -2).Split(',');

foreach (string da1 in data1)
{
     string[] data2 = da1.Split(':');
     opsi.Add(data2[1]);
     Console.WriteLine(data2[1]);
}

return Json(new
{
     info = form["jml_soal"].ToString(),
     data = opsi
});
```